# rxjs - multiple fromEvent with a single Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

So I have set up my observable as follows:

```
var other1 = $("#other");
var textInput = $("#search");
      this.suggestions =
            Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textInput, 'keyup')
              .pluck('target','value')
              .filter( (text) => {
                  text = text.trim();
                  if (!text.length) // empty input field
                  {
                      this.setState({ list: [] });
                  }
                  return text.length > 2;
              })
              .debounceTime(300)
              .distinctUntilChanged()
              .switchMap(term => this.search_company(term))
              .subscribe(
                (response) =>
                {
                  /* Subscription code */
                }
              );
```

I have three other `input type="text"` which uses similar logic, but with the subscription output just a bit different. So I was wondering if there was a way to simplify it by concatenating most of the logic, and just change the subscription resolution while getting the relevant caller, e.g. getting `other1` when the input is from `other1`.

Comment: Is `let()` operator what you're looking for? https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/let.md

Comment: @martin it might be, I'll have to play around with it a bit.

Comment: Why cant you just use `Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("input"), 'keyup') `

Comment: @Skeptor is there a way to get the input caller from that? E.g. the `event`?

Comment: Yes it gives the event obj AFAIK, http://jsbin.com/morolevehu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the code here .

To clarify it gives the `$event` object, so we can get all the info we want.

Document: [RxJS documentation for `forEvent`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md)

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/morolevehu/edit?html,js,console,output

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("input"), 'keyup')
    .pluck('target')
    .map(target=>({id:target.id, value: target.value }))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

gives output:

```
{
    id: 'other',
    value: 'hello' // whatever you typed in the input
}
```

To keep it clean , use a class( ex. 'searchable' ) and query on the input with that class instead of all classes.

`Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("input.searchable"),'keyup')`

**Update: How to persist the id till the end**

Including the original code with the solution.

```
let inputSearch$ = 
  Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent($("input"), 'keyup')
    .pluck('target')
    .flatMap(target=>
             Observable.of(target.value)
             .filter( (input) => {
                  text = text.trim();
                  if (!text.length) // empty input field
                  {
                      this.setState({ list: [] });
                  }
                  return text.length > 2;
              })
              .debounceTime(300)
              .distinctUntilChanged()
              .switchMap(term => this.search_company(term))
              .map(response => {
                  id: target.id,
                  result: response
               })               
    );
```

Instead of taking care of doing different actions for different input, let rxjs take care of that . In `subscribe` only do the end result. For that we can use the `inputSearch$` stream.

```
inputSearch$
    .filter(output => output.id==='other1')
    .pluck('result')
    .subscribe(result => {
     //what you want to do with other1  
    });

inputSearch$
    .filter(output => output.id==='other2')
    .pluck('result')
    .subscribe(result => {
     //what you want to do with other2  
    });
```

Comment: I'll give a try

Comment: So how would I pass the event into my `subscribe` using the code in my question?

Comment: As an update, I call my subscription with a response i.e. `(response) => { code }` see my updated question

Comment: getting a `target.value.filter is not a function`. I'll keep working on it (you can too if you want). Once I get the answer I'll mark.

Comment: Oh, that was stupid of me . will update. Added `Observable.of` , can you try if its fixed

Comment: Such a pleasure !

Comment: Just a note, it seems that `debounceTime` has no effect inside the flatMap and must be placed outside.